# como hacer una busqueda en tiempo real con fetch, php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

aca va el codigo
**esta es mi tabla con sus respectivos id , el de la tabla que es tabla y del cuerpo que es content**

**a continuacion el script, esta hecho con fetch, el cual me retorna data, pero no me filtra **
getData()

```
            search.addEventListener("keyup", event=> {
search_criterio= event.target.value.toUpperCase()
```

getData()

})

function getData(){

```
let search_criterio=''
        let formaData = new FormData()
        formaData.append('search_criterio', search_criterio)

const search = document.querySelector("#search")
search.addEventListener("keyup", event=> {
search_criterio= event.target.value.toUpperCase()
```

})

```
        const tableContainer=document.querySelector("#tabla > #content")
        console.log(tableContainer)
        const resultsContainer=document.querySelector("#resultsContainer")
        const errorsContainer=document.querySelector("#errorsContainer")
        
        

        

    
        
const requestOptions = {
method: 'POST',

body: formaData
};
fetch('load.php', requestOptions)
.then(function(res){

    return res.json();

})
.then(function(data){
    console.log(data)

    tableContainer.innerHTML = data
               console.log(data)

}).catch((response) => {
  console.log(response.status, response.statusText);
    
})



        }
```

require_once 'config.php';

```
 $columns = ['no_emp', 'nombre', 'apellido', 'fecha_nacimiento', ' 
 fecha_ingreso'];
   $search_criterio = isset($_POST['campo']) ? $conn- 
    >real_escape_string($_POST['campo']) : null;


   $where = '';

   if ($search_criterio != null) {



$where = "WHERE (";

 $cont = count($columns);
for ($i = 0; $i < $cont; $i++) {
   $where .= $columns[$i] . " LIKE '%" . $search_criterio . "%' OR ";
}
$where = substr_replace($where, "", -3);
 $where .= ")";


    $sql="SELECT no_emp, nombre, apellido, fecha_nacimiento, 
      fecha_ingreso FROM empleados where no_emp LIKE 
     '%$search_criterio%'";
   $resultado=$conn->query($sql);
   $numrows=$resultado->num_rows;
   $html="";
    if($numrows>0){
  while($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){

    if ($numrows > 0) {
       $html .='<tr>';
       $html .='<td>' . $row['no_emp'] . '</td>';
       $html .='<td>' . $row['nombre'] . '</td>';
       $html .='<td>' . $row['apellido'] . '</td>';
       $html .='<td>' . $row['fecha_nacimiento'] . '</td>';
       $html .='<td>' . $row['fecha_ingreso'] . '</td>';
       $html .='</tr>';
        
          
        } else {
         $html .= '<tr>';
         $html .= '<td colspan="5">Sin resultados</td>';
         $html .= '</tr>';
        }
        
}

}



    }else{

$sql="SELECT no_emp, nombre, apellido, fecha_nacimiento, 
   fecha_ingreso FROM empleados";

  $resultado=$conn->query($sql);
  $numrows=$resultado->num_rows;
  $html="";
   if($numrows>0){
   while($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){

    if ($numrows > 0) {
       $html .='<tr>';
       $html .='<td>' . $row['no_emp'] . '</td>';
       $html .='<td>' . $row['nombre'] . '</td>';
       $html .='<td>' . $row['apellido'] . '</td>';
       $html .='<td>' . $row['fecha_nacimiento'] . '</td>';
       $html .='<td>' . $row['fecha_ingreso'] . '</td>';
       $html .='</tr>';
        
          
        } else {
         $html .= '<tr>';
         $html .= '<td colspan="5">Sin resultados</td>';
         $html .= '</tr>';
        }
        
    }

 }



  } 
   echo json_encode($html, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

**finalmente adjunte el codigo primero pregunta si existe el post "campo" luego si es distinto de nulo hace el select con el campo de busqueda,luego coloca el html a los datos despues si post 0 a null, coloca la sentencia sin where y le inscrusta html y al finalizar lo manda en el json**